# Regex match letters and numbers, except if there are three consecutive (any) letters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex that matches a set of numbers and letters. However I'd like to be able to have any three consecutive letters excluded. This is to prevent accidental forming of words or abbreviations.

The expression I have is the following. It also excludes some similar characters like 0, o, O and 1, i, I, l):

```
^[2-9a-hjkmnp-zA-HJ-NP-Z]{4}$
```

This matches strings like `24rQ` and `1234`. But I'd like it to not match `2dmv`. Because, in this case, this might contain a known abbreviation (positive or negative).

https://regex101.com/r/bbiQWD/1/

A cumbersome way is to write out all combinations. I've written a shorthand (including the similar characters) as an example. But this is not that readable or easy to explain/maintain.

```
(^\d{4}$)|
(^\d{3}\w$)|
(^\d{2}[\d\w]{2}$)|
(^\d{1}[\d\w]{2}\d{1}$)|
(^\d{1}\w{1}\d{1}\w{1}$)|
(^[\d\w]{2}\d{1}[\d\w]{1}$)|
(^\w{1}\d{1}[\d\w]{2}$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bbiQWD/2

**Is there a better way to look for three consecutive letters?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of the pattern, negative lookahead for `.?[a-zA-Z]{3}`:

```
^(?!.?[a-zA-Z]{3})[2-9a-hjkmnp-zA-HJ-NP-Z]{4}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bbiQWD/4

Comment: Thanks. I need to re-examine how to use lookaheads. I was under the assumption it will match only at the exact location in the subject, but I forgot that I can match any character first. Really smart. I've updated your answer with tests for uppercase (not in your original answer). https://regex101.com/r/bbiQWD/5

Answer (score 0):

First things first, `\d` is a subset of `\w`. So `[\d\w]{2}` means `\w\w` or `\d{3}\w` doesn't mean `[0-9][a-zA-Z]`. After all you don't need to calculate all permutations. Use lookarounds instead:

```
^(?!.*[a-zA-Z]{3})[2-9a-hjkmnp-zA-HJ-NP-Z]{4}$
```

[See live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/W9BS82/1)

Comment: The `\d\w` example was just a demo of a workaround, not intended to be correct. Thanks for pointing it out anyway! And of course for the correct solution.